# OAuth - How to create a CustomEndpoint able to extends AbstractEndpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-oauth2

I'm starting my studies in Spring OAuht and I'd like to support OAuth default grant types and ***custom grant types*** in my application.

One of this custom grant types requires a different flow where the user should request a challenge (to be signed for a private key certificate) before receive the access token.

The solution will provide a **CustomEndpoint** to support /oauth/challenge, my idea is to reuse the **AbstractEndpoint** logic.

Is it possible to "register" a new **CustomEndpoint** in Spring OAuth as the existing **TokenEndpoint** and **AuhtorizationEndpoint** ?

Comment: essentially you want to create a custom grant type to support a different flow. For that purpose go ahead and implement org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AbstractTokenGranter and  further if you are using xml based configurations then create a bean for this add this custom grant  in authorization server configuration.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, I would like to access the x509certiicates on the header of the request to authenticate used that decide to use mutual tls as authentication form. I believe the request headers are not available on AbstractTokenGrant class, this is the reason I'm trying to create a endpoint to process the requests before issue the tokens.